# Event is not showing in Full Calender using codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, fullcalendar

I  retrive events from database using events url, but events are not display in fullcalnder??

my Js codes is

```
$('#inspectionCalendar').fullCalendar({

        header: {
            left: 'next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        editable: false,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>inspections/inspections_record',
    });
```

My controller action is :

```
 function inspections_record() {

    echo "[
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2015-08-01'
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2015-02-07'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2015-08-09T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2015-08-16T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Conference',
                start: '2015-08-26'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2015-08-25T10:30:00',
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: '2015-08-25T12:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2015-08-25T14:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Happy Hour',
                start: '2015-08-12T17:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Dinner',
                start: '2015-08-12T20:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: '2015-08-13T07:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                url: 'http://google.com/',
                start: '2015-08-28'
            }
        ],";
}
```

The console of my browser shows the response, but the events are not showing in the calender?

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as an answer.

Comment: look into using Codeigniter  echo json_encode (array object of your event)  in your inspections_record() function

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove the comma at the end of the `JSON` you are echoing, right after the `]`. You also have to surround the names and values in your json with **double quotes** instead of single quotes. That will make `inspections_record()` look like:

```
function inspections_record() {

    echo '[
            {
                "title": "All Day Event",
                "start": "2015-08-01"
            },
            {
                "title": "Long Event",
                "start": "2015-02-07"
            },
            {
                "id": 999,
                "title": "Repeating Event",
                "start": "2015-08-09T16:00:00"
            }
            etc...
        ]';
}
```

**Conclusion:** The events `JSON` that you are feeding to the calendar is not valid `JSON`. This will cause the calendar to not show your events.